# .htaccess pretty url, spaces?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, pretty-urls

Here's my code that allows me to change

```
mydomain.com/?name=something&action=something&other=something
```

to

mydomain.com/something/something/something

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR] 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /index?name=$1&action=$2&other=$3
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /index.php?name=$1&action=$2
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /index.php?name=$1
```

But sometimes the first "something" could be something with a space in it and I'm not quite sure how to format it. e.g. "something very random". I know the url formats it with a `%20` but how could I do this with .htaccess so the url could be

mydomain.com/something very random/somethng/something

also the first word will trail with a `-` and a random number e.g. `-4738`

e.g. `mydomain.com/something very random-4738/something/something`

how would I pick this up with the .htaccess code I am using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this one

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR] 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?name=$1&action=$2&other=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?name=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```